# onlayout gets called twice any ideas?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Below is my code for a custom adapterview. When i put a breakpoint inside onLayout method, it's getting called twice. Also in the hierarchy viewer I am seeing the views getting repeated.

```
package com.me.practice.widgets;    
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.View.MeasureSpec;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.Scroller;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class ScrollableAdapterView extends AdapterView<ListAdapter> {

    public ScrollableAdapterView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView(context);
    }

            //TO detect gestures
    private GestureDetector mGesture;

    protected Scroller mScroller;
    private OnItemSelectedListener mOnItemSelected;
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClicked;
    protected int mCurrentX;
    protected int mNextX;
    private int mMaxX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    private int mLeftViewIndex = -1;
    private int mRightViewIndex = 0;

    protected ListAdapter mAdapter;
    private Queue<View> mRemovedViewQueue = new LinkedList<View>();

    private synchronized void initView(Context mContext) {
        mScroller = new Scroller(getContext());
        mGesture = new GestureDetector(getContext(), mOnGesture);
    }

    @Override
    public ListAdapter getAdapter() {
        return mAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    public View getSelectedView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
        mAdapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelection(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right,
            int bottom) {

        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

        if (mAdapter == null) {
            return;
        }

        renderViews();

        if (!mScroller.isFinished()) {
            post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    requestLayout();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void renderViews() {
        renderFixedColumn(3);
        renderScrollableViews();
    }

    private void renderScrollableViews() {
    }

    //Renders fixed columns...
    private void renderFixedColumn(int fixedColumnUptoIndex) {
        //View fixedLayout= findViewById(R.id.fixedviewsLayout);
        int index=0;

        LinearLayout fixedViewsLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        //fixedViewsLayout.setId(R.id.fixedviewsLayout);

        while (index < fixedColumnUptoIndex) {
            View child = mAdapter.getView(index, mRemovedViewQueue.poll(), this);
            fixedViewsLayout.addView(child, index);
            index++;
        }
        addViewInLayout(fixedViewsLayout, 0, params, true);

        fixedViewsLayout.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth(),
                MeasureSpec.AT_MOST), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                getHeight(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));

        relayoutMeasuredItem(fixedViewsLayout);

    }

    private void relayoutMeasuredItem(View child) {
        final int w = child.getMeasuredWidth();
        final int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
        final int childLeft = getLeft();
        final int childRight = childLeft + w;
        final int childTop = child.getTop();
        final int childBottom = childTop + h;
        child.layout(childLeft, childTop, childRight, childBottom);
    }

    //    
    private OnGestureListener mOnGesture = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return ScrollableAdapterView.this.onDown(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
            return ScrollableAdapterView.this.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX,
                    velocityY);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                float distanceX, float distanceY) {

            synchronized (ScrollableAdapterView.this) {
                mNextX += (int) distanceX;
            }
            requestLayout();

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            Rect viewRect = new Rect();
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                int left = child.getLeft();
                int right = child.getRight();
                int top = child.getTop();
                int bottom = child.getBottom();
                viewRect.set(left, top, right, bottom);
                if (viewRect.contains((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY())) {
                    if (mOnItemClicked != null) {
                        mOnItemClicked.onItemClick(
                                ScrollableAdapterView.this,
                                child, mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i,
                                mAdapter.getItemId(mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i)
                        );
                    }
                    if (mOnItemSelected != null) {
                        mOnItemSelected.onItemSelected(
                            ScrollableAdapterView.this,
                            child,
                            mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i,
                            mAdapter.getItemId(mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i)
                        );
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

    protected boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    protected boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is my activity's oncreate method..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listviewdemo);
    listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

getView method which returns view:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View retval = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.viewitem, null);
    TextView title = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(dataObjects[position]);       

    return retval;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I've not gone in much depth, but to answer your question in brief-

This is because while rendering, a layout undergoes two passes, measure pass and layout pass. It is in the second pass, i.e the layout pass, the parent view positions the children views. Check this out, in Layout section - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: Layout undergoes two passes, that should equate with one onMeasure call and one onLayout call. The observed behavior, however, is two onLayout calls, this is perplexing.